# Is it allowed to use yaml and RouteLocator based routes together spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a usecase where i need to proxy /sample/users/** endpoints. But among all endpoints, i have one endpoint /sample/users/foo for which i need to modify the response body before the response sent to client.
I configured the routes in 2 ways to achieve above.

1. for just forward all matching predicates

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
         - id: users
           uri: ${apphost}
           predicates:
           - Path=/sample/users/**
           filters:
           - RewritePath=/sample/users/**, /users/**
```

2. used RouteLocator for only a specific endpoint

```
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
            .route("profile_route", r -> r.path("/sample/users/foo")
                .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("/sample/users/foo","/users/foo")
                    .modifyResponseBody(String.class, String.class,
                        (exchange, s) -> Mono.just(s.toUpperCase()))).uri(uri))
            .build();
    }
```

This solution is working. But i would like to understand how is this working?
How the yaml and RouteLocator routes are handling /sample/users/** and /sample/users/foo

How does spring cloud decide
java config (routerlocater) for /sample/users/foo and
yaml config for /sample/users/**

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at `GatewayAutoConfiguration`.

Routes defined in yaml are loaded using a `PropertiesRouteDefinitionLocator` (as documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#configuration)), then included in a `CompositeRouteDefinitionLocator` bean (named *routeDefinitionLocator*) and finally processed by *routeDefinitionRouteLocator* bean that returns a `RouteLocator` bean.

This bean, togheter with your custom `RouteLocator`, are "merged" in this composite:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "cachedCompositeRouteLocator")
// TODO: property to disable composite?
public RouteLocator cachedCompositeRouteLocator(List<RouteLocator> routeLocators) {
    return new CachingRouteLocator(new CompositeRouteLocator(Flux.fromIterable(routeLocators)));
}
```

You can fine tune routes ordering using `order` property (not well documented IMHO).